# Powershell get-adcomputer + get-wmi-object

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm setting up a RADIUS server and all works fine except for laptops with a certain Wireless NIC.

I managed to solve the problem, but I wish to have a list of all my AD Domain joined computers with the faulty/outdated NIC (all of our laptops are in several different OU's).

I was thinking something of combining the `GET-ADcomputer -filter *` (to list all computer objects) and combine this with the `get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter | select netconnectionid, name | where name -eq "Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265"`

The PS cmdlets work separately, but I want to match the `get-wmiobject` for each match triggered by the `get-adcomputerCan` you help me out ? :)

Comment: What powershell are you running? Use the newer `Get-CimInstance`. Other than that, you can use a loop of your choice to query against each Computer.  `$ComputerNames = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property Name |Select -Exp Name` then, `foreach ($Name in $ComputerNames) { Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $Name...`, the rest should be logic on error checking if certain criteria isn't met, like not have a wireless NIC.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can approach your script. I do agree with [Abraham's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68036165/powershell-get-adcomputer-get-wmi-object#comment120251932_68036165) comment, if you can, use `Get-CimInstance`:

```
Get-CimInstance win32_networkadapter | Where-Object Name -EQ $match
```

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter *
$match = 'Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265'

$result = foreach($computer in $computers)
{
    $wmi = Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapter | Where-Object Name -EQ $match

    if(-not $wmi){ continue }
    
    [pscustomobject]@{
        ComputerName = $computer.Name
        NetconnectionID = $wmi.NetConnectionID
        Name = $wmi.Name
    }
    
}

$result | Export-Csv 'path/to/csv.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

#### Edit

I haven't tested this nor I have a way of testing it right now, but if this works should be a lot faster, using query language:

```
$computers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter *).sAMAccountName
$match = 'Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265'
$filter = @{
    ComputerName = $computers
    Query = "SELECT NetConnectionID, Name FROM win32_networkadapter WHERE Name = '$match'"
}
Get-WmiObject @filter
```